# Centering and keeping centered a Horizontal dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, navigation, center

I've created a fixed, 100% width nav bar that spans the top of my page; the only problem is I can't get the drop down menu headings to stay centered as the page is resized, or, for that matter, at all... they're floated left at the moment.

Here's the [full screen result](http://jsfiddle.net/LinksTune/qkrxx/embedded/result/) and [the code](http://jsfiddle.net/LinksTune/qkrxx/).

Everything I have tried so far has been breaking the drop-down menu attachments to the menu headings.

Thanks for the help,
Link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have `text-align:center` on the `ul`. That's a good start. Now just add this:

```
#menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none; /* or just remove the float */
}
```

This will center the nav items, but get rid of this too:

```
#menu {
    left: -20px;
}
```

That's breaking the layout and making the first link unclickable.

You also have some extra padding being applied on `:hover`, or something that's making the list items "jump". I'd suggest addressing that as well so the links don't move around.

Comment: Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qkrxx/3/embedded/result/ I have no idea why `.menu_right` has `float:left`, so I didn't touch it - but it needs to be addressed. Use `float:right` instead.